# Reservation system - Available tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been working on this for a few days and I can't figure it out.
Ill hope you can help me out.

I'm working on a reservation system, I would like to check if there are table's availbe on DATE and TIME. 
This is how my database looks like.

[image]

I would like to put the available tables into a select dropdown menu, so on the website it only shows available tables.

If I use the following query I can get the reserverd tables

```
SELECT res.reserveringsnr, datum, begintijd, eindtijd, tafr.tafelnr FROM reserveringen AS res
INNER JOIN tafels_regel AS tafr
ON res.reserveringsnr = tafr.reserveringsnr
WHERE (res.datum = "2013/12/18" AND (res.begintijd BETWEEN "12:00:00" and "14:00:00"))
```

So that query put's out the reserverd table's, but here's where I'm stuck.
I have no idea how to check if a certain table is reserverd on DATE and TIME.

(NOTE: The date and time will be filled in by an variable, but for the example I used just text)

### Edit: Working on @sebt his solution

First of all, to answer your questions

1. Reservations are always on the same day
2. A reservation has a fixed time, 2 hours always.

I've edited sebt's his query to my values:

```
    SELECT t.* FROM
    tafels t
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT tafelnr FROM
          tafels_regel tf
    INNER JOIN
          reserveringen res
    ON tf.reserveringsnr=res.reserveringsnr
    WHERE
    res.datum="2012/01/12" AND
    res.begintijd<"19:00:00" AND
    res.eindtijd>"21:00:00" 
    )
ReservationsAtThisTime
ON t.tafelnr=ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr
WHERE ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr IS NULL
```

This query output's the following result
[image]

As you can see, the query results shows all tafels (12).

I've also exported the tables reserveringen, tafels_regel and tafels to an .csv (see edited .csv below)

### EDIT 2:

Well I've edited my query again, it works for a part.
This is the query ([Screenshot](http://s9.postimage.org/i35e5bin3/querryryryreyry.png))

```
    SELECT t.* FROM
    tafels t
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT tafelnr FROM
          tafels_regel tf
    INNER JOIN
          reserveringen res
    ON tf.reserveringsnr=res.reserveringsnr
    WHERE
    res.datum="2013/01/12" AND
    res.begintijd <= "19:00:00" AND
    res.eindtijd >= "21:00:00" 
    )
ReservationsAtThisTime
ON t.tafelnr=ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr
WHERE ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr IS NULL
```

There are 2 reservations on 2013/01/12. ([Download](http://nivali.com/reserverings_systeem.csv) edited .csv)

Reservation 1: from 19:00 to 21:00 on tafel 1

Reservation 2: from 20:00 to 22:00 on tafel 11 and tafel 12

When I run the query above, the only tafel not showing is tafel 1, since tafel 1 is reserverd from 19:00 till 21:00. But however, from 20:00 till 22:00 tafel 11 and 12 are also reserverd.

As you can see in the query results, only tafel 1 is reserverd.
But when I would make another reservervation from 19:00 till 21:00 and I'm checking for available tafels, then tafel 11 and tafel 12 still shows.

The tafel will be free at 19:00, that's right, but since we always sit 2 hours we can't sit there.

Thanks again @sebt for your input, ill hope you can help me further with this query!

### Problem solved

Thanks for all the help, this is the final query

```
SELECT t.* FROM
    tafels t
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT tafelnr FROM
          tafels_regel tf
    INNER JOIN
          reserveringen res
    ON tf.reserveringsnr=res.reserveringsnr
    WHERE
    res.datum="2013/01/12" AND
    res.eindtijd > "19:00:00" AND
    res.begintijd < "21:00:00" 
    )
ReservationsAtThisTime
ON t.tafelnr=ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr
WHERE ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr IS NULL
```

Comment: i'didnt understood your question.is this query is giving you a problem..?

Comment: I'm going to try the solution below, If that solution fails, ill try to explain my question in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is phrased a bit confusingly, because of the ambiguity between the SQL "Tables" (database tables), and one of the objects in your database, which is (I guess) a restaurant table, called "tafel" in Dutch?

(Let's go on calling them "tafel", as this removes the ambiguity)

To SELECT only the tafels which are *unreserved*, you can LEFT join all the tafels to the set of reservations which are current at [desired time], and return only the tafels which don't have such a reservation:

```
SELECT t.* FROM
    Tafels t
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT tafelnr FROM
          Tafels_regel tf
    INNER JOIN
          Reserveringen res
    ON tf.reserveringnr=res.reserveringnr
    WHERE
    res.Datum=[desired date] AND
    res.begintijd<[desired time] AND
    res.eindtijd>[desired time]
    ) ReservationsAtThisTime
ON t.tafelnr=ReservationsAtThisTIme.tafelnr
WHERE ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelNR IS NULL
```

This would perhaps still need some tweaking, as:

1. Reservations spanning days (i.e. staring on one day and ending on another) would not be handled properly.  (But maybe you don't need this)
2. A table would be shown as available at say 10/01/2012 12:30, when it's in fact reserved from 10/01/2012 12:45 (perhaps no-one is interested in a table that isn't free for at least X minutes - 1 hour? - AFTER their desired start time?).

**EDIT (to answer OP's comment below):**

Looking at your data, I can see that you have Tafel 1 reserved from 19:00 to 21:00 on 12/01/2013.  I can see why you're not getting the expected results (i.e. Tafel 1 should not be shown, as it's not free):

1. The date you're using in the query is in 2012 rather than 2013.  (This originated perhaps in my example, where I used 2012)
2. I designed my example to use a single, point-in-time "desired time".  My thoughts were that the "desired time" would be a point (e.g. 19:30) - and so a reservation starting (e.g.) 19:00 and ending 20:00 would make this desired time unavailable.  Because the "desired time" you're using is a range (19:00 to 21:00), and it happens to be *exactly* the same as the range of the reservation, the "<" and ">" in the query are failing to pick up this reservation as conflicting with the "desired time" ("<=" and ">=" instead would fix this).

However, since you said that all reservations are 2 hours, it would be easier to specify a "conflicting reservation" just using the desired Start time, like this: a "conflicting reservation" is one which occupies any time in the 2 hours following the desired Start time:

a. res.Datum = [desired date]; and
b. res.eindtijd>[desired start time]; and
c. res.begintijd<[desired start time + 2 hours]

I'm not completely sure how the code would work to do the addition of 2 hours (my speciality is MS-SQL rather than MySQL, and date/time operations can be a bit specific to the version of SQL).

**EDIT2 (answering OP's re-redited question):**

To help make things clear, I'll define these terms:

*Existing* booking: already there in the database.  Has a TafelNr, Date, StartTime (begintijd) and EndTime (eindtijd)

*Proposed* booking: the one the user would like to make - naturally it doesn't exist yet in the database, or have a TafelNr.  Has a Date, StartTime, EndTime.

(You've implemented the query using both a StartTime and EndTime for the Proposed booking.  I suggested just using a StartTime, and then using [StartTime+2 hours].  But which of these ways you use doesn't make a difference to the question we're talking about)

You're right that tafels 11 and 12 shouldn't be shown, if the query was working properly.  Your Proposed booking from 19:00 to 21:00 should run into a conflict with the Existing booking from 20:00 to 22:00.  But as you've found, this conflict is not detected as it should be.

The reason is that you've got the Start/End Time comparisons slightly wrong.  The way you've coded it:

```
res.begintijd <= [Proposed Start time] AND
res.eindtijd >= [Proposed End time]
```

would only find an Existing booking to be conflicting if it **spans** the proposed booking: exactly filling the same time, or extending before and/or after the proposed booking.

Imagining the two bookings (existing and proposed) like parallel blocks of Lego sliding along adjacent lines is helpful.  They can make no contact at all (good); or just make contact (one's End=the other's Start: good, no conflict - just!); or the end of one can extend over the start of the other (conflict); or one can span the other, starting at the same time or before the other, and ending at the same time as the other or later (conflict).

This is a trick I've worked out from working with booking systems years ago.  The correct comparison (as in my previous edit above) to find a conflict is:

```
ExistingBookingEndTime>ProposedBookingStartTime AND
ExistingBOokingStartTime<ProposedBookingEndTime
```

or, using your object names:

```
res.eindtijd>"19:00:00" AND
res.begintijd<"21:00:00"
```

This may not make sense at first, but if you think about the Lego blocks it'll make sense.

**Note** that:

**1.** I'm using < and >, not <= and >=, because I assume bookings can extend right up to each other and "touch", as long as they don't overlap;

**2.** Watch out when comparing dates and times - it can give odd results just comparing them as if they were numbers or strings.  I don't know how MySQL handles this, but it's something I'm always careful/paranoid about.

Comment: Yes Thank you sebt, this is correct.
I'm working with it right now, cant figure it out though.
Ill keep you posted..

Comment: Well been playing with this query for a while now The results I got from the database are all tafels, seems like the date and time dont work. 
`SELECT t.* FROM
    tafels t
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT tafelnr FROM
          tafels_regel tf
    INNER JOIN
          reserveringen res
    ON tf.reserveringsnr=res.reserveringsnr
    WHERE
    res.datum="2012/01/12" AND
    res.begintijd<"19:00:00" AND
    res.eindtijd>"21:00:00" 
    )
ReservationsAtThisTime
ON t.tafelnr=ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr
WHERE ReservationsAtThisTime.tafelnr IS NULL`
I've also made a screenshot [link](http://goo.gl/tqC47)

Comment: Edited, the OP. hope you can help me out again!

Comment: Thanks! it works! finally! I would realy like to upvote ur comments, but I can't vote untill I got 15 rep. Thanks again, going to edit the OP with the final result.

Comment: No problem!  Glad it works.  I'd forgotten about the 15 rep restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not really understand your database structure. But to get you on track:

1. You can simply query all your tables
2. You exclude reversed tables from the result set

Something like:

```
SELECT tafelnaam FROM Tafels WHERE tafelnr NOT IN (SELECT tafelnr *OF YOUR RESEVED TABLES*)
```